# TypeError: _reshape_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'newshape'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was trying to fit a CNN model to some input data df, where df is (`921 x10170`).

My code:

```
from numpy import *
X = df.iloc[:,0:10165]  
X = X.to_numpy()                    
X = reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1])
X_1 = X[:,0:10080,:]          
X_2 = X_train[:,10080:10165,:].reshape(921,85)   
Y = df.iloc[:,10168:10170]
```

and incurred error:

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
>   last)
>    in ()
>       17 X = df.iloc[:,0:10165]
>       18 X = X.to_numpy()
>   ---> 19 X = reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1])
>       20 X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:]
>       21 X_train_2 = X_train[:,10080:10165,:].reshape(921,85)
>
> <**array_function** internals> in reshape(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: _reshape_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'newshape'

I tried a few ways but none of them worked. What is the issue here? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to mention what you are reshaping here:

```
X = reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1])
```

You need to change it to:

```
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
```

And it will solve your problem